# Merging sorted arrays with defined length in Python (good practices)

Tags: python, arrays, array-merge

I have encountered interesting case during practicing writing Python algorithms on Leetcode.

*The task: "You are given two integer arrays nums1 and nums2, sorted in non-decreasing order, and two integers m and n, representing the number of elements in nums1 and nums2 respectively." The result should  be stored inside the nums1 (which has length m+n, where n represents those elements that should be ignored from nums1 and added from nums2).*

I have came with the simples solution, It is giving the expected results in VSCode but it is not passing test cases designed in LeetCode.

I am wondering why... What I am missing?

```
`class Solution(object):
    def merge(self, nums1, m, nums2, n):
        """
        :type nums1: List[int]
        :type m: int
        :type nums2: List[int]
        :type n: int
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
        """

        nums1 = sorted(nums1[0:m] + nums2[0:n])



nums1 = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
m = 3
nums2 = [2, 5, 6]
n = 3

solution = Solution()
result = solution.merge(nums1, m, nums2, n)
print(result)`
```

Please note I am a beginner. I am probably not taking something important into consideration. I guess it might me unwisely updating nums1 because I am loosing information about array, but is there anything else?

I couldn't find code for test cases in LeetCode to understand why problem occurred. Maybe anyone could help and guide me where to look for it?

Comment: What are the reasons for tests failing?

Comment: Recommended reading: Ned Batchelder’s "[Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)"

Comment: @TurePålsson this talk is a pure gold! Thanks

Comment: @matszwecja the case is I don't know how to access the code for the test cases in leet code. Here is the link to the mentioned task: https://shorturl.at/jADW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sorted` function generates a new list object, but the solution requires modifying the existing `nums1` variable.

```
> origin_list = [3,2,1]
> origin_list
[3, 2, 1]
> answer = sorted(origin_list)
> answer
[1, 2, 3]
> answer is origin_list
False
```

Try to use methods of the list in your solution like: `pop()`, `append(...)`

Pay attention to the comment:
**None Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify `nums1` in-place, so you can assign to a slice covering the entire list.

```py
nums1[:] = sorted(nums1[:m] + nums2)
```

Note that this can be solved with time complexity `O(n + m)` without sorting the entire list.